# Hovering over images while having them scale with the browser

Tags: html, css, scaling

I'm trying to make an image that changes into another image when hovered over that also scales based on the size of the browser.

The css code I have so far is this:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#a_Cscaleskb{
   width:0px;
   height:0px;
   background:url('../images/a_Cscaleskb_up.gif');
   padding:47px 114px;
}

#a_Cscaleskb:hover {
   background: url('../images/a_Cscaleskb_over.gif');
}
```

with the html:

```
 <img id="a_Cscaleskb" src="../../images/a_Cscaleskb_up.gif" alt="" />
```

This works great for changing the image on hover but when I shrink down the browser it doesn't change.

Another piece of code I've tried is this:

```
#a_Cscaleskb{
background:url('../images/a_Cscaleskb_up.gif');
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

#a_Cscaleskb:hover {
background: url('../images/a_Cscaleskb_over.gif');
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

This css scales properly upon hovering, but you can see both images laying over each other. I know it's also possible to use javascript but I'm trying to avoid using it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem it would be so much easier to tweak your code and understand the problem

Comment: I couldn't get the second example to work on jsfiddle. It works on my project but overlays.
http://jsfiddle.net/D9f3M/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale your images according to browser size then use this sneaky bit of code:

```
   img{max-width:100%;width:auto;height:auto}
```

that's what i've used in my gallery page in [www.busyfeet.rachelgallen.com](http://www.busyfeet.rachelgallen.com/gallery.html) - give it a look and see it in action